# Python assign to slice vs remove from end?

Tags: python, list, recursion, slice

Imagine we want to create all lists of length 5 that start with `[0, -1]` and end with 3 integers that are all 2s or 3s. One such list (of 8 possible lists) would be `[0, -1, 2, 2, 3]`. Here is some simple (buggy) recursive code for it:

```
def op(a):
    print(a)
    if(len(a) < 5):
        a.append(2)
        op(a)
        print("pre 2", a)
        a = a[:-1] #.pop()
        print("post 2", a)
    if(len(a) < 5):
        a.append(3)
        print("pre 3", a)
        op(a)
        print("post 3", a)
        a = a[:-1] #.pop()

op(a)
print(a)
```

However, this code does not work and outputs some random lists. However, if we replace the line `a = a[:-1]` with `a.pop()`, it works completely fine. Why is there a difference?

Comment: What does it print? How did that intermediate output differ from what you expected?

Answer (score 1):

- `a = a[:-1]` creates a new list object and rebinds it to the name `a`. All prior stack entries that refer to the name `a` will be referencing the original, untruncated list.
- `a.pop()` performs an in-place operation that removes the last element. It does not change what the name `a` refers to. All stack entries will refer to the truncated list.

Other ways of removing the last element *without* rebinding the name are

- `a[:] = a[:-1]`. This will take the new list `a[:-1]` and assign it to the *elements* of `a`. Remember that any expression of the form `a[x] = y` calls `type(a).__setitem__(a, x, y)`, which is generally an in-place operation on `a`, while `a = x` rebinds the name `a` entirely.
- `del a[-1]`. This is equivalent to calling `type(a).__delitem__(a, -1)`. Again, an in-place operation very similar to `pop` except it doesn't return the element.
- `a[-1:] = []`. This is sort of the inverse of `a[:] = a[:-1]`. Instead of resigning as the slice of all elements you want to keep, you assign empty to the slice you want to remove.